# Display a popup on selected index change of a dropdownlist in mvc4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to display a popup on selected index change of a dropdownlist. The popup should contain 3 buttons i.e Yes, No and cancel. On click of Yes/No button in the popup I need to do some database changes based on the selected item in the dropdownlist and on click of Cancel button the popup should disappear. Please help me.
my View is as follows :

```
@model FND.Models.ViewLender

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Change Lender";
     }

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.Label("Change Lender : ")
        @Html.DropDownList("Ddl_Lender", Model.ShowLenderTypes, new { id = "lenderType" })
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Description)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need a function that binds to the selected index change on your dropdown and the contents will be similar to below:

```
    private void Ddl_Lender_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Sure", "Some Title", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel);

        if(dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            //do something
        }
        else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
        {
             //do something else
        }
        else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
             //do something else
        }


    }
```

You could swap the if statements for a switch as well, but this should give you all you need.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**
Just remembered that this is MVC and not a windows application so the above wont work, but you may be able to use some of the logic.